# Metasploit Wifi Modules Asking for lorcon2

Tags: wireless, metasploit, kali-linux

I'm using Metasploit Framework for Wifi Exploiation, on Backtrack R2, but I'm getting this error:

```
The Lorcon2 module is not available: no such file to load -- Lorcon2
```

But actually, I have installed Lorcon2, still I'm getting this error.

I have Installed this Lorcon2 - http://802.11ninja.net/svn/lorcon/tags/lorcon2-200911-rc1/

There are lots of questions regarding the same but not even one proper answer.

Comment: have you run through the steps here http://blog.opensecurityresearch.com/2012/05/installing-lorcon2-on-backtrack-5-r2.html it does mention the same error that you're seeing and has a solution for it...

Answer (score 1):

If the first [link](http://blog.opensecurityresearch.com/2012/05/installing-lorcon2-on-backtrack-5-r2.html) is unable to work for any reason, an alternative solution might be found here as well:
[BackTrack Forums](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=2046)

Cheers,